# Why does sublime consider <!------- (multiple dashes) a syntax error

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a .html file that is working perfectly fine but for some reason Sublime 3 decides that it has invalid code, check the image below:

[image]

Any idea why that's happening and how to fix it without having to modify the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 spec states (my emphasis):

> Comments must start with the four character sequence `U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN`, `U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK`, `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` (`<!--`). Following this sequence, the comment may have text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with a single `>` (`U+003E`) character, nor start with a `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` character (`-`) followed by a `>` (`U+003E`) character,
>
> ***nor contain two consecutive `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` characters (`--`),***
>
> nor end with a `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` character (`-`). Finally, the comment must be ended by the three character sequence `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, `U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN` (`-->`).

So that's why it's complaining. As to how to fix it without changing the code, that's trickier.

Your contention that it works is no different really to C developers wondering why they need to worry about undefined behaviour because the code they wrote works fine. The fact that it works fine in one particular implementation is not relevant to portable code.

My advice is to actually change the code. It's not valid, after all, and any browser (current or future) would be well within its rights to simply reject it.

---

As an aside after some historical digging, it appears this is not allowed because SGML, on which HTML was based, had slightly different rules regarding comment.

On sensing the `<!--` token, the parser was switched to a comment mode where `>` characters were actually allowed within the comment. If the `--` sequence was encountered, it changed to a different mode where the `>` would *end* the comment.

In fact, it appears to have been a toggle switch between those two modes, so something like `<!-- >>>>> -- xyzzy -- >>>>> -->` was possible, but putting a `>` where the `xyzzy` would end the comment.

XML, for one, didn't adopt this behaviour and HTML has now modified it to follow the "don't use `--` within comments at all" rule, the reason being that hardly anyone *knew* that the comments behaved in the SGML way, causing some pain :-)

Comment: The same goes for [XML comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments); the standard cites compatibility with SGML as a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer pax